# How to enable DomainRuntimeMBean?

Tags: oracle11g, jdeveloper, weblogic11g

I've been trying to installing JDeveloper and Weblogic server , and when trying to login as first time as Administrator in console of weblogic ,
The Server give me this error `A required MBean Server is disabled which prevents the proper operation of the Weblogic Administration Console Please enable the DomainRuntimeMBean Server and the Edit MBean Server in this domain's configuration.`

also I was maked search in "Oracle Forums" i found answer like that :
`Also check to make sure there were no errors in the server log during
startup or when you connected to the MBean Server. Sometimes errors can
occur that cause the MBean Server to appear to be disabled.` but that answer doesn't help me.

> The question is "How to enable `**DomainRuntimeMBean**`?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [this link](http://weblogicfordummies.blogspot.com/2008/10/wls10please-enable-domainruntimembean.html), try to delete the `pending` folder within your domain root and restart the server. The default domain has got some corruption in the console settings.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using PC_NAME use URL 
e.g. instead of My_PC:7001/console --> use 127.0.0.1:7001/console - Amartya Bandyopadhyay